# Version of Hurwitz' Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of analytic complex functions on a region $A$ converging uniformly on every closed disk in $A$ to $f$. Assume that $f$ is not identically zero, and let $z_0 \in A$. Then $f(z_0)=0$ iff $z_0$ is a limit point of the zeros of $\{f_n\}$, which means that $f_n(z_0)=0$ for an infinite number of $n's$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ There is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $f_{n_k}(z_0)=0$ for all $k$, so $f_{n_k}(z_0) \to 0$. Since uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, we have that $f_{n_k}(z_0) \to f(z_0)$. By uniqueness of the limit, $f(z_0)=0$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ By the Hurwitz' Theorem, it is true that there is sequence $z_n \to z_0$ and an integer $N$ such that $f_n(z_n)=0$ for all $n \geq N$. But I've failed to prove that $f_n(z_0)=0$ for an infinite number of $n$'s.

Comment: “$z_0$ is a limit point of the zeros of $\{f_n\}$”  means that $f_n(z_n)=0$ for some sequence $(z_n)$ converging to $z_0$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove that $f(z_0) = 0$ implies “$f_n(z_0)=0$ for an infinite number of $n's$” because it does not necessarily hold.

A counterexample is $f_n(z) = z-1/n$ which converges uniformly to $f(z) = z$. We have $f(0) = 0$, but  $f_n(0) \ne 0$ for all $n$.

The correct equivalence would be that $f(z_0) = 0$ if and only if there is a sequence $(z_n)$ in $A$ with $z_n \to z_0$ and $f_n(z_n) = 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$. See for example [An application of Hurwitz theorem from Conway's Complex Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348933/an-application-of-hurwitz-theorem-from-conways-complex-analysis).

Comment: Why does "$z_0$ is a limit point of the zeros of $\{f_n\}$" mean that $f_n(z_n)=0$ for some sequence $\{z_n\}$ converging to $z_0$? Is that a definition or does it have to be proved? Because if I use the usual definition of limit point (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point), I get that $z_0$ is a limit point of the set of the zeros of $\{f_n\}$, which is the set $B=\{z : f_m(z)=0$ for some $m \}$ iff there is a sequence $\{z_n\}$ converging to $z_0$ such that for each $n$, there is $m$ such that $f_m(z_n)=0$, but how to assure that $m=n$, so that $f_n(z_n)=0$?

Comment: Or are you taking the set of the zeros of $\{f_n\}$ as $B=\{z : f_m(z)=0$ for all $m \}$?

Comment: @Twink: The usual definition is that $z_0$ is a limit point of a set $S$ if there are points $z \ne z_0$ in $S$ arbitrarily close to $z_0$. But that definition does now work here: With $f_n(z) = (1-1/n)z \to f(z) = 0$ the set of all zeros of the $f_n$ is just $\{ 0 \}$ and that has no limit point. Therefore I tried to interpret it in a way that the equivalence works.