# If $f_n \to f$ in $M(G)$, and $a$ is a pole of $f$, then there is a sequence ${a_n}$ in $G$ s.t. $a_n \to a$, and $f_n$ has a pole at $a_n$ for $n>>0$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem from a past exam:

> Let $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set, $\{f_n\}$ a sequence in $M(G)$, and $f$ a meromorphic function such that $f_n \to f$ in $M(G)$. Suppose $a \in G$ is a pole of $f$. Show that there is a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $G$ such that $a_n \to a$ and $f_n$ has a pole at $a_n$ for sufficiently large $n$.

I was trying to find a ball $B$ centered on $a$ such that $\frac{1}{f_n} \to \frac{1}{f}$ in $H(B)$, and then apply Hurwitz's theorem to say that as we shrink the radius of the ball, since $\frac{1}{f}$ will always have a zero at $a$, $\frac{1}{f_n}$ will also have at least one zero in the smaller balls for $n$ sufficiently large.

So, for some $\epsilon$ such that $B(a,\epsilon) \subseteq B$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $f_n$ will have a zero in $B(a,\epsilon)$. We denote the zero of $f_N$ by $a_N$. Because we need a sequence $a_n \to a$, I tried to make $\epsilon$ smaller to find the subsequent terms in the sequence, but for this smaller value of $\epsilon$, if we apply Hurwitz's theorem again to the smaller $\epsilon$-ball, we know that for sufficiently large $n$, $f_n$ will have a pole in the ball, and so we can find some $M > N$ such that $f_M$ has a pole in the smaller ball (but I think it is possible for $f_{N+1}$ to not have a pole in this smaller $\epsilon$-ball). In this way, we can find a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ such that a corresponding sequence of poles $\{a_{n_k}\}$ exists such that $f_{n_k}$ has a pole at $a_{n_k}$ for $n$ sufficiently large, but I am not sure how to get a sequence $a_n$ such that for sufficiently large $n$, every $f_n$ has a corresponding term $a_n$ in the sequence such that $f_n$ has a pole at $a_n$.

Comment: Apply https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348933/42969 to $1/f$ and $1/f_n$.